# Issue With iwlwifi driver

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.10, iwlwifi

I'm using a *Dell Inspiron Laptop* and running ubuntu **19.10**.
After applying an update from software center and restarting i am unable to access wifi.

After looking in logs i saw the following  https://pastebin.com/fDbXXnPX
In addition 
The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`
is

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4234]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Some things i have already tried:

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

result: nothing installed linux-firmware was already up to date

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

When i ran these commands nothing was shown and the issue was not fixed

I read somewhere that the issue could be related to secure boot being enabled however on my system secure boot has been disabled the whole time.

Comment: Which model are you using, which year? Secure boot can be easily found in the dell bios, but it is not a guarantee. Did sudo apt upgrade finished installing everything?

Comment: My apologies i misread the bios settings secure boot has been disabled the whole time. This is the model of the laptop in question https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/laptops-notebooks-and-2-in-1-laptops/inspiron-13-7000-2-in-1/spd/inspiron-13-7391-2-in-1-laptop/cn73113. Now when i run sudo apt upgrade i get 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

Comment: Strange. Can you show me a screenshot of your settings (or camera photo)? Is there something for wireless or wired connections?

Comment: My guess is that something went wrong with the kernel. You could try LTS Ubuntu, it should be working correctly there. You could also try switching to other kernel with Ukuu

Comment: here are some screenshots of the bios settings and gnome settings. strangely wifi nolonger shows up https://ibb.co/7nC7dW6
https://ibb.co/M9723MM
https://ibb.co/smjYjzk

Comment: Can you try going to 5.2 with Ukuu? What does uname -r output?

Comment: That Fixed it! using version 5.3.0 results in no issues

Comment: Nice, happy that this helped you

Comment: Thank you very much!